# What is the right space between a math operator and its subscript?

Tags: math-operators, operator-space

I am trying to define a command for a math operator `\mathcal P_\mathrm{ext}`. So I thought some candidates for this:

- `\mathcal P_\mathrm{ext}(H)`
- `\operatorname{\mathcal P}_\mathrm{ext}(H)`
- `\DeclareMathOperator{\Pm}{\mathcal P}` and `\Pm_\mathrm{ext}(H)`

[image]

There are some differences. I didn't expect the space between `\mathcal P` and the subscript when I use commands like `\operatorname`. I wonder *what the right one is*. Or should I put the subscript inside the `\operatorname`? (but it seems strange to use like that...)

Here is the MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath, amssymb}
\DeclareMathOperator{\Pm}{\mathcal P}

\begin{document}
\begin{align*}
    &\mathcal P_\mathrm{ext}(H) \\
    &\operatorname{\mathcal P}_\mathrm{ext}(H) \\
    &\Pm_\mathrm{ext}(H)
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

Comment: in all three cases the input syntax should be `_{\mathrm{ext}}` it is not a good idea to rely on the weird parsing rules that make `_\mathrm{ext}` appear to work.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[image]

```
\documentclass[fleqn]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath, amssymb}
\DeclareMathOperator{\Pm}{\mathcal{P}}
\showoutput
\begin{document}
\begin{align*}
    &\mathcal{P}_{\mathrm{ext}}(H) \\
    &\operatorname{\mathcal P}_{\mathrm{ext}}(H) \\
    &\Pm_{\mathrm{ext}}(H)\\
    &\mathop{\mathcal{P}_{\mathrm{ext}}}(H) 
\end{align*}


a $\log x$


a ${}\log x$

\end{document}
```

The specific example makes the answer a bit trickier than it would otherwise have been. I would  say that the most logical markup would be `\mathop{\mathcal{P}_{\mathrm{ext}}}` as you want the subscripted term itself act as a `\mathop`.

However the reason that you see different spacing here is because you are on the right hand side of an alignment where implicitly the expression is prefixed by `{}` so you are getting a thin space from the `\mathop` to separate it from the (invisible) preceding term. So it is like the second `\log` example I added to the example here/  So why in the vast majority of cases the `\mathop` spacing for `\log` is the right thing the extra space here is probably not right and should be removed by `\!` or by using a form that does not give a `\mathop`, eg `{\Pm}`

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Yes, I am using `P_{ext}` itself as the operator. What I am confused is the following: both `\operatorname{P}_{\mathrm{ext}}` and `\operatorname{P_{ext}}` *should mean* the operator `P` with the specific restriction `ext` (I am also using operators with other subscripts.) But they print different result. So what should be the convention that I use?

Comment: @TheGreatSeo if you just use operatorname around the P then you lose the font-specified kerning to bring the ext under the slope of the P, as you are no longer subscripting a simple character but a tex-constructed mathop tem

Comment: So I may always need to define an operator with more effort if there is a chance for it to have a subscript.. Thanks for the advice!

Answer (score 13):

If you use `\operatorname{\mathcal{P}}_{\mathrm{ext}}`, TeX cannot kern the subscript.

If you just need “ext” as subscript, you can define

```
\DeclareMathOperator{\Pme}{\mathcal{P}_{ext}}
```

If the subscript is variable,

```
\newcommand{\Pm}[1]{\operatorname{\mathcal{P}_{#1}}}
```

and call it as `\Pm{ext}`.

Full example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\DeclareMathOperator{\Pme}{\mathcal{P}_{ext}}

\newcommand{\Pm}[1]{\operatorname{\mathcal{P}_{#1}}}

\begin{document}

$\Pme(H)$

$\Pm{ext}(H)$

\end{document}
```

[image]

If you prefer the `_` notation:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{xparse}

\NewDocumentCommand{\Pm}{e{_}}{%
  \operatorname{\mathcal{P}\IfValueT{#1}{_{#1}}}%
}

\begin{document}

$\Pm_{ext}(H)$

\end{document}
```

[image]

Note that in any of the above case you just type in `ext`, because it will be typeset as part of `\operatorname`; `\mathrm` is not needed.

Comment: Thanks for the various methods for the desired function, especially the last one!